# How to add a new control to form using Reactive Form without an error: "ERROR InternalError: "too much recursion"?

Tags: javascript, angular

My question is related to form building using Angular Reactive Form.

Let's analyze my problem using an easy example. I've created a very easy form with only two controls: 'price' and 'tax'.

The goal is to catch given by the user values from price and tax controls, next make a sum (price + tax) and the result assign to the form as a third control 'totalPrice'.

This is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.scss']
})
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {
  productForm:FormGroup
  totalPrice:number;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.productForm = this.buildForm();
    this.countTotalPrice();
  }

  private buildForm() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      price: ['', {validators: [Validators.required]}],
      tax: ['', {validators: [Validators.required]}],
    })
  }

  countTotalPrice() : void {
    this.productForm.valueChanges.subscribe( val => {

      if(val.price || val.tax) {
        this.totalPrice = parseFloat(val.price) * parseFloat(val.tax);
        this.addGrossPrice(this.totalPrice);
      }
    });
  }

  addGrossPrice(v) : void {
    if(v > 0) {
      this.productForm.addControl('totalPrice', new FormControl(v));
    }
  }

}
```

So, I'm able to count the 'totalPrice' and pass it as the third control, but unfortunately, the code above indicates an error:  "too much recursion".

My question is how in this particular case avoid the recursion error, or maybe you may recommend some better way to achieve my goal.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is happening because everytime you add a control, the valueChanges on the form group also emits, so you're in a never ending loop of adding controls on value change. the simplest thing here is to always have the control on the form and just set the value and supress events:

```
  private buildForm() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      price: ['', {validators: [Validators.required]}],
      tax: ['', {validators: [Validators.required]}],
      totalPrice: ['']
    })
  }

  addGrossPrice(v) : void {
    if(v > 0) {
      this.productForm.get('totalPrice').setValue(v, {emitEvent: false});
    }
  }
```